# Correct synonymous to expression "still into you"?

Tags: synonyms, lyrics

In the USA there is Paramore band. They have wrote nice song [Still into you](https://youtu.be/OblL026SvD4) in 2013. In lyrics clear all for me except title. "**Still into you**" what does it mean in this context?

***Context***

> *Yeah after all this time*
>
> *I'm still into you*.

**Question:**

Please, give me correct analogy. Is it "fall in love" or sort of sex or something other?

Comment: It means she's still "madly in love" like during the days when they first became involved. What usually happens over time, is that some of the passion in a relationship disappears, but the song is saying this is not the case in her feelings.

Comment: @AlanCarmack sorry, but can you please explain to me how one can tell if something is a dupe? I have read the rules, etc. And I cannot FIND the place where one can search. Thank you. I have asked this question three times and no one answers me.

Comment: It's not quite the same as the explanation which has been marked as a duplicate since the duplicate is saying strong interest whereas in the song it's something stronger than that, of course context is very important and informal phrases like this are usually more general than specific.

Comment: @Lambie In the upper right hand corner of every window, there is a field with light grey text which says _Search Q&A._ Enter search text there (e.g. "into you" for the current question) and press _enter._ Then, of course, you have to read the Q&A to see if it's a good match.

Comment: @P. E. Dant Right. I finally have managed to "see" it. THANKS!